# What causes phpVirtualBox's remote desktop server port to be crossed out?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, centos

I am running VirtualBox 4.3.34 on Centos 6 host with Windows 7 guest, have installed guest additions, and also installed phpVirtualBox.

Previously, I was able to remote desktop with a Windows 7 client, but no longer can.  I recently did a yum update which might have caused the problem.

I noticed that phpVirtualBox's "Remote Desktop Server Port" is crossed out and "Remote Display" is greyed out and not accessible.

What causes this?  What do I need to do to enable remote desktop?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing extension pack.

Turned out the extensions that I previously installed went away after updating vbox.  I reinstalled them and rebooted machine.